# Twitter API : Error: Request failed with code 403 (image upload)

Tags: api, twitter

There are a few things I don't understand about the Twitter API.
I am using the following package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-api-v2

Which allows me to connect to a twitter account.
I recover all the credentials of the connected account.
(Among other things, I manage to recover user data and send simple tweets)

I am trying to upload an image.

So I have the following code:

```js
const result = await client.v1.post(
        "media/upload.json",
        {
          command: "INIT",
          media: file,
        },
        {
          prefix: "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/",
        }
      );
```

And I got the following error returned to me:

`Error: Request failed with code 403 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you'll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve (Twitter code 453)`

I have read and write permissions.
(since I manage to send tweets)

I understand that the V2 api of twitter does not allow image upload, but here I am using V1?

Can you give some information ?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this? I spent a few hours building the OAuthV2 flow into my app, but I'm getting 403 on uploading media - tweeting is fine.

Comment: I'm starting to think to effectively upload images I'll have to rebuild my flow to use oauth v1. Have you managed to use both flows?

Comment: it's also happening to me too with the simple upload endpoint. starting to think read and write permissions aren't enough for this one, but I couldn't find this stated in the docs

Comment: actually, it is mentioned in the docs. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/getting-access-to-the-twitter-api section - Step four. Essential access doesn't cover v1.1 endpoints.